# How to know if the replaced tab for a previously discarded tab is the same?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

So you discarded a tab and later when you click on the discarded tab , it reloads the page.

First:

> `OnUpdated()` gets called with `changeInfo.discarded === true`

and on reload:

> 1. `onUpdated()` gets called with `changeInfo.discarded === false`.
> 2. `onUpdated()` gets called with `changeInfo.status === complete`.

How, would I know that the `tab` in `Step 2` is the replacement for the discarded tab. The `tab.id` has changed by now and the `tab.discarded` property of the `newtab` has also been reset. So, ducktyping?

Comment: Can you not get the url of each tab?

Comment: `url` alone is an issue in case there's mutiple tabs with the same `url`. So, I just need to check the `index` property of the `newtab` along with the `url` and the `windowId`. Thanks for the prompt response

Comment: Perhaps there is also date/time of tab creation and form/qs data. You could create a hash of all that you have and use that as a de facto id in lieu of a real id.

Comment: That's a cool idea. I'll probably do that. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!